# How do I grab nsindex from one view controller and implement it in another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

```
         UIButton *btnUserImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnUserImage setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 80, 60)];
        [btnUserImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [btnUserImage setTag:indexPath.row];
        [btnUserImage addTarget:self action:@selector(btnUser_clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btnUserImage];
```

Hello, I have this one method I am trying to implement but the problem is the btnuserimage tag isn't working because index path.row is in another .m file. The bottom code is what I am trying to implement to the code above.I have to have the method above in another controller for it to work. Any suggestions or tips on what to do. Basically what I am asking is the bottom code needs to be implemented to another view controller so that way the above code will work.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a SharedClass and pass all the required values to and from that.
Or, 
You can create a global variable and use that in both the classes.

But I would suggest to go with sharedClass.

And for future reference, if something gets changed dynamically, then you can go for Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a public method in your 'one' view controller like the bellow. And call it at you 'another' view controller.

```
// in OneViewController a public method
- (void)addButtonWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
{
    [btnUserImage setTag:tag];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
    ...
    [oneViewController addButtonWithTag:indexPath.row];
    ...
}
```